# Proof of special case of $\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}’(t)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

**Question:**
Is my proof correct? I'd ask you keep in mind that I know of a similar, less complicated proof that involves using that $\big|\vec{r}(t)\big|^2=c^2$ as a first step and going from there.

**Need to prove:**

If $\big|\vec{r}(t)\big|=c$, where $c$ is constant, then

$$\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}^\prime(t)=0$$

**My proof:**

Let $\vec{r}(t)=\langle x(t),y(t),z(t)\rangle$ where $x,y,$ and $z$ are continuous and have continuous first derivatives. Then $\vec{r}^\prime(t)=\langle x^\prime(t),y^\prime(t),z^\prime(t)\rangle$. We could then say that $\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}^\prime(t)=x(t)x^\prime(t)+y(t)y^\prime(t)+z(t)z^\prime(t)$. Now, integrate both sides to get that

$$\int\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}^\prime(t)dt$$$$=\int\Bigl(x(t)x^\prime(t)+y(t)y^\prime(t)+z(t)z^\prime(t)\Bigr)dt$$

For the RHS, you introduce a substitution variable for integration, $u=x(t), v=y(t), w=z(t) \Rightarrow du=x^\prime(t)dt, dv=y^\prime(t)dt, dw=z^\prime(t)dt$.

$$\int\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}^\prime(t)dt=\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{v^2}{2}+\frac{w^2}{2}+C=\frac{c^2}{2}+C=K$$

Where $C$ is a constant of integration and $K$ is a new constant. Now differentiate both sides to get

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}^\prime(t)dt=\frac{d}{dt}K\Rightarrow\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}^\prime(t)=0$$

Comment: Why not forgo integrating and simply differentiate both sides of the expression $\vec r\cdot \vec r=c^2$? You simply reversed this to integrate $\vec r\cdot \vec r'$.  But this is a valid way forward.

Comment: I know what you mean, differentiating what you said is better, this is just the way I thought of at first. Thank you though for the input, appreciated.